# What is the correct way to "overwrite" bootstrap colors? (and optionally other CSS selectors)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Searching on topic how to customize the original bootstrap CSS I mainly found power tools and generators what are emit a "patched" bootstrap.css to use instead the original.

I am very beginner in bootstrap, so first I would like to see clear the best practices before I invest hundreds of workhours to do something dumb and not recommended thing.

My question: Is this the way? I mean editing (automatically or manually) the bootstrap.css. Sounds not good for me, I am hoping I missed something.

Is there any alternative way, say creating a tiny mycustom.css and only define the differences there. Could anyone point out how to redefine just the standard colors?

Comment: Bootstrap uses LESS/SASS which is a 'language' that compiles to CSS - It has predefined variables which are sprinkled throughout the project - Changing the values of those variables - e.g some primary colors etc would alter the overall theme of Bootstrap but you need to have some basic SASS or LESS knowledge

Comment: I understand that the "source" is not the CSS instead the LESS/SASS. What I do not see clearly: If anyone modify (heavily) the source for a paricular version, then when the new version issued how to "reapply" the very same modifications. Seems a not structured practice. I _must_ misunderstand or miss somethinge here...

Comment: You can create your own CSS rules to override Bootstrap's and load them after Bootstrap has loaded. Note that you might also need to make sure your rule's specificity has a greater weight than Bootstrap's, but that's usually only needed if you see that your rules aren't being applied.

Comment: [Use LavishBootstrap](http://www.lavishbootstrap.com/) to alter your colour scheme.

Comment: @j08691 OK, but if the original used variable say for the color, then all those colors are "hard coded" in CSS level. Can I overwrite them with a simple few line CSS?

Comment: I have not seen it mentioned yet but for simple modifications (such as colors) Bootstrap provides a page to get a custom version. http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: @marcelo: That method is my problem

Comment: @jbutler483: I took a look to the tool. Do I understand correctly it generates a CSS (or LESS) what are hopefully overwrites the all hardcoded colors in the bootstrap.css? And in case if no breaking changes in the next bootstrap.css it can be used over the new version too? (at least this is the concept)

Comment: @g.pickardou: Yes. Much like the 'answers' of 'add a custom css' - that does it for you. Personally, though, I don't like bootstrap. But Lavish will sort out the colouring for you.

Comment: I was referring to overriding the resultant CSS, not using the LESS that generates it. You can override anything Bootstrap does, it just depends on what rules you create, where you load them, and their specificity.

Answer (score 1):

Best option if you`re are beginner is to generate a new bootstrap.css with the oficial generator http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ and so you also could test changes in other Bootstrap variables. I think that overwrite css properties with your own CSS file can be painful sometimes...

Best option (need time to learn) is import Bootstrap as LESS (not CSS) and then create your own variables.less file, where you will define values for all Bootstrap variables that you want to overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/customize-bootstrap/) website demonstrates exactly how to override Bootstrap's CSS without doing naughty things like using `!important` in your own CSS files (which should be avoided). You simply create a new custom.css file and add in your overriding styles there.

I would not directly edit the LESS/SASS Bootstrap files.

Comment: nobody said to edit them directly - it's standard practice to keep the original but create your own variables

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides It was mentioned.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides I just pointed out not to do that. I agree, keeping the original is best.

Answer (score 0):

Don't edit bootstrap.css.

Instead create your new css file and add new values in that file and make sure that this new file is loaded after bootstrap.css .

Answer (score 0):

For small changes include your own .css file after including bootstrap, overwriting the css components of bootstrap. This is what bootstrap advises (check bootstrap components page)

> body { padding-top: 70px; }
>   Make sure to include this after the core Bootstrap CSS.